# Is it possible to use a local zip file for terraform module source

Tags: terraform

I can't seem to find anything online so I'm doubting its possible but thought I would ask just incase.

I am trying to use a local zip file as a module source, has anyone ever done anything like this or have you always just used local directory or remote zip on S3 etc.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
module "network" {
  source = "./network.zip"
}
```

Comment: Sadly, its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with local files, Terraform expects to find an already-expanded directory of `.tf` files. Terraform supports archive files only for transmission of a set of files together over the network.